# Imposing an Electric Field to Eliminate Drift

Tags: classical-mechanics, electric-fields

[image]

Hello, the part I need help with is the last part about imposing a uniform electric field to eliminate the constant horizontal drift. But this seems impossible because the drift is *constant*, while the electric field is ultimately connected to the particle's acceleration, so if we don't impose any $\textbf{E}$-field, the particle will retain its drift, while if we have impose any non-zero $\textbf{E}$-field, then eventually the particle will begin to accelerate in the direction of the $\textbf{E}$-field, and clearly this doesn't count as "eliminating the drift". How am I supposed to do this?

Note that if the magnetic field is pointing along the $x$-axis (so $\textbf{n}$=$\hat{i}$), and the particle has initial position $\textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{0}$, initial velocity $\dot{\textbf{x}}(0)=v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j}+v_z\hat{k}$, and the uniform electric field is given by $\textbf{E}=E_x\hat{i}+E_y\hat{j}+E_z\hat{k}$, then using the notation of the problem, the particle's trajectory is given by:
$$\textbf{x}(t)=\biggr(\frac{qE_{x}}{2m}t^2+v_xt\biggr)\hat{i}+\biggr(\frac{(qE_z-mg)t}{m\alpha}+k_1\sin(\alpha{t})+k_2(1-\cos(\alpha{t}))\biggr)\hat{j}+\biggr(k_1(\cos(\alpha{t})-1)+k_2\sin(\alpha{t})-v_y/\alpha\biggr)\hat{k}$$
where $k_1=\frac{v_y}{\alpha}-\frac{qE_z-mg}{m\alpha^2}$ and $k_2=\frac{v_z}{\alpha}+\frac{qE_y}{m\alpha^2}$.

Comment: Is it true that the particle, under the influence of gravity and a magnetic field traces a path which is helical with _constant_ "horizontal" (I would have chosen "vertical" but whatever) drift? Is the pitch of the helix really constant, or does the particle accelerate due to gravitation? I suspect the "constant drift" is wrong.

Comment: Well earlier for instance I calculated that if the magnetic field is given by $\textbf{B}=B\hat{i}$ along the $x$-axis, and the particle starts at the origin and is launched with initial velocity $v\hat{i}$ along the direction of the magnetic field, then it does indeed "drift" parallel to the $xy$ plane with constant velocity while exhibiting a circular motion in the $yz$ plane.

Comment: It doesn't accelerate under gravity? Interesting.